# Vim: Adding * symbol between numbers and the left parenthesis

Tags: regex, vim

I have thousands of lines in a file in the following format:

```
x1(t) = 1.568(1-t) + 5.145(1-t)**2 + ... (other terms)
x2(t) = 3.347(1-t) + 1.304(1-t)**2 + ...
x3(t) = 7.016(1-t) + 1.901(1-t)**2 + ...
x4(t) = 0.843(1-t) + 5.335(1-t)**2 + ...
....
```

As you can see, there is no `*` sign between the numbers and the left parenthesis. I could record a macro to fix that ,but for some reason I do like to use the `:substitute` command with regular expressions, instead.

I've tried the following:

```
:%s/[0-9]([0-9]/*(/g
```

But that does substitute also the digits before and after the left parenthesis. I don't know how to match the parenthesis alone without matching the numbers before and after.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
:%s/[0-9]\zs(\ze[0-9]/*(/g
```

This is roughly equivalent to a [`[0-9]\K\((?=[0-9])` PCRE regex](https://regex101.com/r/18QZw2/1) and matches:

- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `\zs` - omit the text matched so far from match memory buffer
- `(` - a `(` char
- `\ze` - end of consuming pattern, the rest is context
- `[0-9]` - a digit must appear after `(` (the digit is just context, not part of a match).

Comment: @Navaro `sed` has no support for non-consuming patterns, you need to post-process matches. GNU `grep` supports PCRE patterns with the `-P` option.

Comment: @Navaro Which feature? `\zs` - *anything, sets start of match*, `\ze` - *anything, sets end of match* (see [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html))

Comment: @Navaro In regex terminology, these are *lookarounds*, lookahead or lookbehind. But there is also a `\K` operator, and Vim `\zs` / `\ze`